# Using Google Play Services in Android ; is there a way to get the Location from only GPS?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

Using Google Play Services 's Location Service , is there a way to specify that we get the Location only from GPS device on the android device?

Comment: I think that is not clear enough what you really need. Could you add more details, code ....?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) should be a handy guide in telling you how to request your location strictly from the GPS. Be sure to read carefully in the [Requesting Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates) section.

Granted, this is not using the Google Play Services Location Service, but I believe the difference between the two is that, by using Google Play, you can skip the step of calling both `GPS_PROVIDER` and `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. Additionally, Google Play Services Location Service stores the most recent [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) in the `GoogleApiClient` so you're not completely out of luck when neither of the providers are working.

**Edit**

Short answer - No

Long answer:
[According to Google's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6fa9ad4afcd762aea519ff61811386c23d18ddb2/packages/FusedLocation/src/com/android/location/fused/FusionEngine.java), they use the same functions I listed earlier. As far as higher accuracy is concerned, that is obtained through the combination of `GPS_PROVIDER` and `NETWORK_PROVIDER` data. A workaround could possibly be passing the `FusedLocationProviderApi` GPS-only locations through the [setMockLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#setMockLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.location.Location)) method.

Comment: Well Google clearly recommends that Goggle play services as the preferred way to obtain Location moving forward. It seems that it is more than just simple api. It offers higher accuracy, low-power geofencing, and more. So I just want to know if there is a way to do that in Goggle Play Services